# How to re-arrange list like this (python)?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

For example, list `to_be` consists of: 3 of `"a"`, 4 of `"b"`, 3 of `"c"`, 5 of `"d"`...

```
to_be = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", ...]
```

Now I want it to be like this:

```
done = ["a", "b", "c", "d", ... , "a", "b", "c", "d", ... , "b", "d", ...] (notice: some items are more than others as in amounts, but they need to be still in a pre-defined order, alphabetically for example)
```

What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: You want to remove every item that is equal to his predecessor?

Comment: Try the `Counter` [collection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presuming I am understanding what you want, it can be done relatively easily by combining [`itertools.zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

We first group the items into sets (the `"a"`s, the `"b"`s, etc...), we zip them up to get them in the order your want (one from each set), use chain to produce a single list, and then remove the `None` values introduced by the zipping.

```
>>> [item for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(*[list(x) for _, x in itertools.groupby(to_be)])) if item]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

You may want to separate out some of the [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to make it a bit more readable, however:

```
>>> groups = itertools.zip_longest(*[list(x) for _, x in itertools.groupby(to_be)])
>>> [item for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(groups) if item]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

(The given version is for 3.x, for 2.x, you will want [`izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).)

As always, if you expect empty strings, 0, etc... then you will want to do `if item is not None`, and if you need to keep `None` values in tact, create a sentinel object and check for identity against that.

You could also use [the `roundrobin()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) given in the docs, as an alternative to zipping, which makes it as simple as:

```
>>> list(roundrobin(*[list(x) for _, x in itertools.groupby(to_be)]))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

As a final note, the observant might note me making lists from the `groupby()` generators, which may seem wasteful, the reason comes from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
>   groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
>   So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list.

Answer (score 2):

```py
to_be = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"]
counts = collections.Counter(to_be)
answer = []
while counts:
    answer.extend(sorted(counts))
    for k in counts:
        counts[k] -= 1
    counts = {k:v for k,v in counts.iteritems() if v>0}
```

Now, `answer` looks like this:

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is fastest, but here's my stab at it:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> def sort_key(a):
...     d[a] += 1
...     return d[a],a
...

>>> sorted(to_be,key=sort_key)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

wrapped up in a function:

```
def weird_sort(x):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    def sort_key(a):
        d[a] += 1
        return (d[a],a)
    return sorted(x,key=sort_key)
```

Of course, this requires that the elements in your iterable be hashable.

Answer (score 0):

A bit less elegant than Lattyware's:

```
import collections
def rearrange(l):
    counts = collections.Counter(l)
    output = []
    while (sum([v for k,v in counts.items()]) > 0):
        output.extend(sorted([k for k, v in counts.items() if v > 0))
        for k in counts:
            counts[k] = counts[k] - 1 if counts[k] > 0 else 0
    return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it "by hand and state machinne" should be way more efficient - 
but for relatively small lists (<5000), you should have no problem taking vantage of 
Python goodies doing this:

```
to_be = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d","e", "e"]


def do_it(lst):
    lst = lst[:]
    result = []

    while True:
        group = set(lst)
        result.extend(sorted(group))
        for element in group:
            del lst[lst.index(element)]
        if not lst:
            break
    return result

done = do_it(to_be)
```

The "big O" complexity of the function above should be really BIG. I had not event ried to figure it out.