# Are python sort keys guaranteed to be called only once?

Tags: python, sorting

While answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391422/748858), I ended up creating a sortkey function which modified a dictionary in order to save state which would then be used for subsequent items in the sort.

While my answer *seemed* to work, my question is this: Is it actually defined in the python documentation that the sort-key would only be called once per object?  Is this is an implementation detail of Cpython?  Or is the sort-key actually called more than once and I got the correct answer only out of luck?

The documentation of [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) states:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly)

Which I don't think implies that `key` will only be called once per element ... but it could be stated elsewhere.

Obviously I ask as this has consequences on any sort-keys which have a side effect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the section of the docs you link:

> In general, the key and reverse conversion processes are much faster than specifying an equivalent cmp function. This is because cmp is called multiple times for each list element while **key and reverse touch each element only once**.

That would seem to be a "yes" ...