# How does Python sort() time complexity change with lambda functions with non O(1) complexity?

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

I have an array 'logs', where `logs = ["1 art can", "2 own kit dig", "3 art zero", "4 art can"]`. Each element is a string which has a serial number, followed by a bunch of words. I need to sort the array in the lexicographical order of the string contents (excluding the serial number). If two strings in the array have the same content, I need to sort them based on their serial numbers.

I used the sort() function in combination with a lambda function which in turn uses the split() function. Usage below:
`logs.sort(key=lambda x: (x.split()[1:], x.split()[0]))`

I know that the time complexity of sort() is O(nlog(n)) and split() itself has a O(n) time complexity. Assuming there are n strings, each of length m, what is the effective time complexity of `logs.sort(key=lambda x: (x.split()[1:], x.split()[0]))`?

Comment: The sorting complexity is a function of the size of the list. The key complexity is a function of the size of a list element. So they're different inputs.

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't think `sort()` has to call the key function for every comparison. It can call it once for each element (perhaps by caching). So it won't be multiplicative, it will be additive.

Comment: @Barmar Good point.

Comment: The class of efficiently will still be `O(n logn)` though.

Comment: Use `lambda x: x.split(maxsplit=1)[::-1]`

Comment: `key` was specifically added to ensure any element manipulation is done at most once. The older `cmp` argument was a function that would be called once per *comparison*, meaning you might have to extract the same key from an element multiple times if it was involved in multiple comparisons.

Comment: On the downside, doing the key calculation only once causes O(n) space complexity.

Comment: @o11c true although I believe the `sort` implementation already uses an auxilliary list anyway

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but closely related: [Are python sort keys guaranteed to be called only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13391553/12299000)

Comment: @chepner Purely out of curiousity, do you have a source for this? I would have guessed `key` was added because the vast majority of the time, a `cmp` function is written as extracting two keys (i.e. repeated code) and then comparing them in their natural order.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states this: "The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated **once** and then used for the entire sorting process." (Emphasis mine.) However, the function has to actually *extract* the key to make this a speed improvement. `functools.cmp_to_key`, for example, creates a "function" (really, a class) that gets called (instantiated) once per element, but doesn't actually "memoize" anything; it just remembers the argument so that the original comparison function is called each time it is needed.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) (emphasis mine):

> Both list.sort() and sorted() have a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element **prior to** making comparisons.

So all the keys are computed once, not while doing all the comparisons. The complexity of performing all the key computations is added to the complexity of the sorting. So the overall complexity will be whichever has the larger order.

Answer (score 1):

A single pass is done and the key function (the fact that you use a lambda expression is completely irrelevant) is applied once to each element. So that operation is `O(m*n)` where m is the maximum size of each string and n is the size of the list. However, if we assume `m` is small or non-varying, we can just say it's `O(n)` and the overall algorithm stays `O(n*log n)`.

Suppose instead, though, you had a list and you want to sort the items by their *frequency*. And you naively do

```
sorted(mylist, mylist.count)
```

Well *now* the application of the key function is `O(n**2)` on the size of the list. The sorting itself is still `O(n log n)`, but now your overall algorithm is `O(n**2)`

Note, one way to avoid the above would be to do

```
sorted(mylist, Counter(mylist).get)
```

Using a `collections.Counter` object